# ngFor get data on click and display it under clicked element

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

What I want:

I want to print objects from `objectArray` one by one, and after clicking on it to display additionalObject from `AdditionalObjectArray` right under it like this:

```
object1Name
object2Name
object3Name
object4Name
```

when I click on object1Name for instance I want to get:

```
object1Name
    additionalObject1ForObject1
    additionalObject2ForObject1
object2Name
object3Name
object4Name
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let object of objectArray" >
    <div (click)="populateAdditionalObjectArray(object.id)">
        {{object.name}}
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="showAdditionalObjects">
        <div *ngFor="let additionalObject of AdditionalObjectArray">
            {{additionalObject.name}}
        </div>
    </ng-container>
    <hr>
</ng-container>
```

This is what I get when I click on `object1Name`:

```
object1Name
    additionalObject1ForObject1
    additionalObject2ForObject1
object2Name
    additionalObject1ForObject1
    additionalObject2ForObject1
object3Name
    additionalObject1ForObject1
    additionalObject2ForObject1
object4Name
    additionalObject1ForObject1
    additionalObject2ForObject1
```

It prints out `additionalObject1` and `2` from `Object1` for every entry. Why is this and how to do it correctly?

Comment: If somebody reputable enough comes across this question, please let me know why am I getting downvoted. Is it noot clear what I want ? Is my attempt not enough?Is this question you can easily find solution online? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you told it to do. For every loop of the outer ngFor there is an inner div waiting until the `showAdditionalObjects` boolean is true and then outputting the contents of the `AdditionalObjectArray` item.

In your click event code you are presumably adding the the sub-items of object one to `AdditionalObjectArray` and setting `showAdditionalObjects` to true.

There are several ways to solve it but by adding an index to the outer loop and adding a new variable you can control which div shows.

Change the code as below and add a new variable in the ts file called showIndex.
Pass the index into click code and set `showIndex` to that value.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let object of objectArray; let i = index;" >
   <div (click)="populateAdditionalObjectArray(object.id, i)">
    {{object.name}}
   </div>
   <ng-container *ngIf="showAdditionalObjects && showIndex === i">
      <div *ngFor="let additionalObject of AdditionalObjectArray">
        {{additionalObject.name}}
      </div>
   </ng-container>
   <hr>
</ng-container>
```

Now only the clicked div will show the sub items. If you want multi divs to show their sub items you need to come up with a different way of using the index of the loop to control the visibility.